# how to get all IP in VNIC [Oracle Cloud Using API]

Tags: oracle, instance, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

i have a **instance** related with **VNIC** in this VNIC I have **33 IP Adress** but when i use **[GetVnic commande](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/iaas/20160918/Vnic/GetVnic)** `GET /20160918/vnics/{vnicId}` it's return only one Adress IP ,
how i can to return all the ips ?

Comment: do you mean you have 33 Private IP Addresses assigned to single VNIC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at [this script](https://github.com/oracle/oci-python-sdk/blob/master/examples/get_all_instance_ip_addresses_and_dns_info.py) as an example on how you can do this.